# Commit VBA color changes Changes in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a map that is populated with rectangles in access. When you click on a square it changes to red via `Me.Box12.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)` I need these changes applied via the VBA to stay permanent if I close the database or switch views etc. Currently they do not. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How do I set the value in the colors table via a variable? and how do I then pull that color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the colour settings to a table and read this when launching your app and apply the colours when opening the forms - or enter the form into design mode, apply changes, and save.

Comment: This needs to be appended via clicking the button/rectangle. So I dont think that I could store this information unless I specified the code to somehow pipe to a table and then pull that appended data on load.

Comment: That's exactly the suggestion. Put the color in a table. Opening a form in design view and saving is impossible if you are distributing your app compiled anyway (ACCDE).

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the method for saving it on button press to the table. How is this achieved?

Comment: Use a recordset. Open the record with your settings: Me!Box12.BackColor = rs.Fields("BackColor").Value. To save use: rst.Edit : rst.Fields("BackColor").Value = somecolourvalue : rst.Update